# Creating a count based of JSON response - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm attempting to pull some useful information from a web services JSON that isn't technically included. The JSON will return something like the below:

```
[ {
   "Val1": "Value One",
   "Status": "Okay",
   "endDate": "2017 - 09 - 30 T00: 00: 00 "
   }, 
   {
   "Val2": "Value Two",
   "Status": "Okay",
   "endDate": "2017 - 08 - 24 T00: 00: 00 "
} ]
```

Is there a way to find the difference in number of days between the current date (Dynamic) and the date in the endDate result, and add that to a count?

This would then be used for something like this:
  - End date within 10 days: #
  - End date within 20 days: #

etc.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: First, 1. you need to new a Date object with the endDate; 2. endDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime() is the ms differences btwn current date and the end Date; 3; you can calculate more coarse grained time difference based on the delta ms.

Answer (score 1):

Please reference below code snippet:

```
let endDate = new Date(JsonArray[index].endDate.replace(/ /g, ''));
let msDelta = endDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime();
let dayDelta = Math.floor(msDelta / 1000 / 3600 / 24);
```

**WORKING DEMO:**

```js
var json = [ {
   "Val1": "Value One",
   "Status": "Okay",
   "endDate": "2017 - 09 - 30 T00: 00: 00 "
   }, 
   {
   "Val2": "Value Two",
   "Status": "Okay",
   "endDate": "2017 - 08 - 24 T00: 00: 00 "
} ]

json.forEach(obj => {
  let endDate = new Date(obj.endDate.replace(/ /g, ''));
  let msDelta = endDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime();
  let dayDelta = Math.floor(msDelta / 1000 / 3600 / 24);
  console.log(`End date within ${dayDelta} days`);
});
```

Comment: Fantastic - thank you very much for taking the time tibetty and @Endless to show me this. I hate to be burdensome, but how should I move the different counts to different variables? i.e "Expiring within 0-30 days" and "Expiring within 31-50 days?

Comment: Make a simple comparison btwn dayDelta and the interval limits (e.g., 0 - 31, 31 - 50), and then you can assign your description accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js

Eg.:

```
differenceDate = moment(Date1).diff(date2, "days").format();
```